# Alias cannot be found in certificate keystore

Tags: code-signing, keytool, jarsigner, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to sign a jar file using a code signing certificate. The alias name includes some special characters (Turkish characters). The alias name is similar to the following:
bi?li?şi?m teknoloji?leri? eği?ti?m's comodo ca limited id

When I try to sign a jar file, the following error occurres:

> Certificate chain not found for: bi?li?şi?m teknoloji?leri? eği?ti?m's
>   comodo ca limited id.  bi?li?şi?m teknoloji?leri? eği?ti?m's comodo ca
>   limited id must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a
>   private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

I tried to change the alias name by  using keytool (jdk) utility, but again, since the alias name was not found, I couldn't succeed.

When I looked at the details by keytool and I see the entry type is "PrivateKeyEntry", so I don't think this error is about a missing private key.

The problem seems related to unrecognized character issue.

How can I solve this problem and proceed to signing my jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support team from the certificate company responded to my email. They wanted to renew the certificate without using Turkish characters in the company name. As I guessed, the problem was related to unrecognized characters.